# How to change the alias for the core forum landing page?

Tags: 7, nodes

Core forums sets the landings page to /forum. I need this changed to /another-page/forum. I know I can change the forum posts using pathauto, but I need to change the alias for the top-level forum landing page. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the core path module:

http://example.com/admin/config/search/path/add

Comment: Thank you. I always assumed that core path was only for creating nice seo aliases for node and term ids. thanks.