# How to change the alias for the core forum landing page for drupal 6?

Tags: 6, path-aliases, nodes

Core forums sets the landings page to `/forum`. I need this changed to `/some-other-name`.the forum posts can be changed using pathauto, but I need to change the alias for the top-level forum landing page. I have tried playing with url aliases but can't find anything to solve my purpose.
I googled and found this exctly same [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48606/how-to-change-the-alias-for-the-core-forum-landing-page) on drupal stackexchange, but I need to do it for drupal-6. Please help.
 Edit: im also using advanced-forum module

Comment: On a Drupal 6 site, I went to `admin/build/path/add` and in the `existing system path` I entered `forum` and in the `path alias` I entered `somewhereelse/forum` and it worked, so, what am I missing here?  Do you need the forum names/categories aliased as well?

Comment: I searched long but could not find this path setting.btw i was searching in admin/setting, and yes i need forum /names/categories aliased as well.. let'see if  i can manage it with url aliases..thank you so much.. I will look for it and report back.

Comment: sorry for reporting so late. thank you so much, it worked like a charm..thank you so much..sometimes solutions could be so simple that we simply overlook them!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jimajamma commented, the answer was really simple.. just go to `admin/build/path/add` and in the existing system path I entered forum and in the path alias I entered `/some-other-name` and it worked, and btw if you need it for drupal 7, the go to `admin/config/path/add`.

Comment: For Drupal 8 go to:  /admin/config/search/path/add