# Pathauto and forum paths

Tags: 8, path-aliases, nodes

I can generate urls to forum topics fine, but pathauto appears to be stubbornly refusing to generate urls for Forums and containers no matter what patterns I try to use.

I even tried to alias them in core alias - [as suggested for Drupal 7 here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48606/how-to-change-the-alias-for-the-core-forum-landing-page) -  but aside from the fact that the pages then returned 404 results I will probably have users adding forums in the future so really need to be in a position to generate them.

I want my forum urls to be of the form `/private/discussion/forum-name` and I would like to be able to have my container point to `/private/discussion` and see a list of the available forums there. Or at least alias the main forum output page.

Comment: After 1 year, issue still persists.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to the issue reported here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2010132. See the patch in comment [#107](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2010132#comment-12180051) for a patch.

I've confirmed that the patch applies to the current Drupal 8.4 branch, the tests pass, and the aliases get generated as expected.